# android:layout_above works just in 2 of 3 cases

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create three lines with buttons, the first and last line are fixed to the top and the bottom of my screen, the middle one is fixed to the center-vertical.

I could use android:layout_above to fix two TextViews to the top and bottom button-line - but the center-textview is shown in the middle of nowhere and ruins the layout if I try different device-screens. The effect was the same when I fixed my problem-textview to the center-vertical. Then my middle button line was in the middle of nowhere although I used android:layout_above.

What should I do?

Thank you,
Christian

[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx8zavn5k077th4/screen.jpg

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- 
1 
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/play"
    android:text="1. Dialog abspielen"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/record"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pause" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stopsol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stoprec"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause" />

<!-- 
2 
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/record"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/record"
    android:text="2. Ihre Aufnahme"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/record"
    style="@style/btnStyledark_khaki"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stoprec"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stoprec"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stoprec"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stoprec"
    style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paussol" />

<!-- 
3 
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/playsol"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/playsol"
    android:text="3. Aufnahme + Lösung abspielen"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playsol"
    style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/paussol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/paussol"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stopsol"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopsol"
    style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paussol" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Please explain clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx8zavn5k077th4/screen.jpg I want the second textview above the second button line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml is really messy, you should organize the items in layouts. Here is one way to do it for your second item:

```
<!-- 2 -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/stop"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2. Ihre Aufnahme"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/record"
        style="@style/btnStyledark_khaki"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stoprec"
        style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, I still had problems to put the textviews directly above the Button-Line with your approach. That's why I put textviews and buttons in one line / one linear container now - dividing them like this: android:layout_width="0px" |      android:layout_height="wrap_content" |
          android:layout_weight="1"